# What are the results of change and options in Live Templates in idea's settings?

Tags: java, templates, intellij-idea

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGDen.png)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gfnkm.png)

[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfJMn.png)

1. The effective area is the size class of the repeated range of presence
2. This list of " comment,comumer function,declaration ..."  can be customized
3. Can you put restrictions on the shortcut definitions in effect, e.g., /ser and ser can both be triggered?
4. Role of "Use static import if possible" and "Shorten FQ names" in option
5. expand with can be triggered by either enter or space.

   Part of the change setting takes effect in the third image .
   There's a video that explains the scope of what's in effect and the documentation.